# How to split string of Arrays into actual Arrays? - javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I want to split a string of Arrays into an actual array in Javascript(react).

Original String :

`[" 103.116.32.2",1225],[" 163.53.79.51",677],[" 103.116.32.30",651],[" 103.116.32.1",174],[" 10.6.27.6",40],[" 184.26.162.104",36],[" 184.26.162.97",35],[" 10.57.10.88",27],[" 172.16.59.56",24],[" 8.8.4.4",22],[" 103.116.32.26",18],[" 8.8.8.8",17],[" 103.116.32.14",16],[" 192.168.180.5",14],[" 216.239.35.0",10],[" 10.6.24.135",9]`

Result I want :
nested array with these values

```
newArray = [
[" 103.116.32.2",1225], 
[" 163.53.79.51",677], 
[" 103.116.32.30",651] ...etc
];
```

What I have tried:

I have tried `string.split(",")` but this doesnt work because **there is a comma inbetween the inner arrays**. So the results gives newArray = [[" 103.116.32.2"] , [1225] , [" 163.53.79.51"] , [677]]

Comment: so JSON.parse it

Comment: What you are showing as your "original string" isn't a string. There's also no such thing as a "string of arrays". Please clarify.

Comment: Modify whatever is giving you this string to give you a JSON string instead.

Answer (score 5):

Your source string is pretty close to valid JSON, you just need to wrap it in `[]` to be able to parse it:

```js
const source = '[" 103.116.32.2",1225],[" 163.53.79.51",677],[" 103.116.32.30",651],[" 103.116.32.1",174],[" 10.6.27.6",40],[" 184.26.162.104",36],[" 184.26.162.97",35],[" 10.57.10.88",27],[" 172.16.59.56",24],[" 8.8.4.4",22],[" 103.116.32.26",18],[" 8.8.8.8",17],[" 103.116.32.14",16],[" 192.168.180.5",14],[" 216.239.35.0",10],[" 10.6.24.135",9]';

const result = JSON.parse(`[${source}]`);

console.log(result);
```